# Regex href parsing

Tags: java, regex

a regex question in java.
I'm scraping Id numbers from a  element href attribute. I have a bunch on links like these in a string:

`<a href="http://www.someplacelol.com/pdf/14669/Whatever/Doesntmatter">Whatever</a>`

After the 'pdf' and slash comes an Id number, which I'm interested in.
So I must get all Id's from multiple occurences of this kind of url in the string. What would be the best regex for it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse non-regular statements. Use an HTML parser for this such as Jsoup. That's what they're made for. That's what they do best.

Comment: Any solution to this is in danger of being brittle.  That said, once you've parsed your HTML and got at your attribute value, I'd consider using java.net.URI to normalise the path before extracting the path segment.  For example, `http://www.someplacelol.com/pdf/../pdf/14669/Whatever/Doesntmatter` ought to be equivalent to your URL above.

Comment: Let me sum up the above comments with "can you give us more details about your problem"?  Do you know that you'll always have lowercase HTML tags, with no nested links and no attributes such as style appearing before href?  In that case the subset of HTML you're dealing with is a regular language and can be parsed with a pleasant regex. In most real life cases links aren't going to be nested and can be handled with regexes fine so provided you're ok with some brittleness regex is a reasonable approach that sacrifices robustness for developer time.

Comment: Yes, it's always lower case. The other thing that i must mention, is that after the "pdf/" there are cases where alphabetical characters are present, they must be excluded. The Id is always numerical and the length of the numerical value is unknown. What is certain, is that there is always "pdf/" in front of it and "/" after it (quotations only for higlighting purposes).

Comment: If there can be other HTML attributes in front of the href you will have a much more complicated regex.  It's still possible with regexes (barely) but I've never got this to work 100%, may be better to use HTML parser in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the url will be exactly this, your regex can just be:

```
someplacelol\\.com/pdf/([0-9]+)/
```

Comment: will pick up instances where this happens outside of <a> tags, which may or may not be acceptable for OP's purpose.

Comment: Combined with an HTML parser, this is perfect because it matches only the URL (or part of it).

Comment: I used the Jsoup library to get the href attributes, so this worked actually while iterating though them. But i still must remove the "pdf/" from the beginning and "/" from the end. It's trivial from now on of course, but would appreciate for the syntax of how to exclude these things.

Comment: Ok, got it. Missed groups. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex artist but you should be able to get the url out of the  element with:

```
\<a\s.*?href=(?:\"([\w\.:/?=&#%_\-]*)\"|([^\"][\w\.:/?=&#%_\-]*[^\"\>])).*?\>
```

The first group will contain the URL.

From there you should be able to extract the number without too much difficulty.  I tested that link on the source of this page and it was able to correctly identify all of the HREFS in all of the `a`s.

Please don't comment and say `It breaks for <a id="<<<>><><<>>href=" href="<a href=">` because OP has provided in his description of the problem that ridiculous abuses of the HTTP standard such as this one will not be present in his trail cases.

Also, if for some weird reason, an element has 2 hrefs, only the first will be grabbed.  You could probably address that if you cared.

Edit: added whitespace requirement after `<a` so it won't match things like `<asdffsdfsfg href="lol">`.